# Pass cookie back to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am writing a single-page application with CanJS. For one of models, every time I save a new item, the application sends the normal `POST` request. However, there is a specific cookie that is returned in the `HTTP` response that I would like to send back to the server on `GET` requests when fetching an item.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any request should send cookies automatically

Comment: @ExplosionPills I thought so, too, but, for some reason, the cookie is not being sent. I looked at the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cookies specific to an application are passed automatically to server in request header. **Make sure that the cookie which you want to send is of the same application**.

This you can check by looking into the cookies of your browser. Make sure that the cookie which you want to send has **Domain** as your application name. Like all stackoverflow cookie will have domain value as **.stackoverflow.com**

You can refer to this tutorial which talks about creation and setting of cookie in JavaScript : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Hey. Although I already knew this stuff, I will accept your answer since you took your time to answer. I was playing around with the HTTP headers and I noticed that the cookie wasn't being sent back to the server. The reason I asked is because I thought that it was something specific to CanJS. Thanks. [:)].

Comment: I also facing same issue.
I have 5 cookies in my application.
Among them only 4 cookies are being sent to server.
One of the cookie is not sending to server.
Is there any way to send it?

Comment: If the domain is same then the cookies will be sent automatically else you can set it through javascript. Check the link which i have attached.